# How to updated v-bind:Class items using button in vue

Tags: arrays, vue.js, class, bind

I tried to delete/change the class in the lottery numbers set (array) that has been selected by click the number, but when the button remove is clicked the class on the All selected number remains unchanged.
Please the Help

Here's the code :

```
<div class="body-border">
      <b-row no-gutters style="margin-top:10px;">
          <b-col  cols="2" v-for="lotre in lotres" :key="lotre.id">
            <div :class="{chooselotre: lotre.isActive}" class=" mx-auto " @click="pickticket($event,lotre.id); editColor(lotre);">                         
                    <p class="text-lotto text-center"> {{lotre.id}} </p>
              </div>
            </b-col>                            
      </b-row>
      <b-row>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-pill btn-pick-clear" @click="removeAllTicket()">clear pick</button>                                    
      </b-row>                                   
 </div>


<script>
    import Vue from 'vue'
    
    export default {  
        data: () => ({
            lottos:[],
            lotres : [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    isActive: false,
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    isActive: false,
                }
                ,
                {
                    id: 3,
                    isActive: false,
                },]
    )},
    methods: {                      
            removeAllTicket: function() {
            this.lottos.splice(0,this.lottos.length);
            this.lotres.slice(0,this.lotres.isActive);
            },
            
    },
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The class binding should be like

```
:class="{'chooselotre': lotre.isActive, 'item-lotre2': lottos.length >= 6,  'item-lotre': lottos.length <= 6}"
```

and make sure that the removeAllTicket() works fine and does the required change for the arrays

Comment: I was change, but still same. that i looking for the  removeAllTicket() can change the class, can you help?

Comment: The respective condition should evaluate to true in order to enable the particular class. So please check if the length of the array is changing by printing console logs in your method

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, just to add looping in the removeAllTicket ().

```
for (lotre of this.lotres){
    if (lotre.isActive) {
     lotre.isActive = false
         }
       }
```